# Why PyCryptoDome's 3DES algorithm uses 128-bits or 192-bits key instead of 56-bits?

Tags: python, cryptography, pycrypto, pycryptodome

According to Wikipedia, 3DES's cipher uses a 56-bits encryption key to encrypt data; but Pycryptodome's 3DES class uses either 128-bits or 192-bits encryption key. Also both Pycryptodome's AES's and 3DES's encryption speed are same, output is similar. Am I doing something wrong or is this 3DES a bit different?

Here's my code to encrypt data with 3DES algorithm in Python:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3
from Crypto import Random

key = 'Sixteen byte key'
iv = Random.new().read(DES3.block_size)
cipher_encrypt = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_OFB, iv)
plaintext = "Some data to encrypt with 3DES"
encrypted_text = cipher_encrypt.encrypt(plaintext.encode("utf-8"))

cipher_decrypt = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_OFB, iv)
cipher_decrypt.decrypt(encrypted_text)
```

Comment: Where does it say that Triple DES uses a 56-bit key? Read the Wikipedia article more carefully, especially the chapter _Keying Options_. Regarding speed and the claim that both are equally fast: How did you determine that?

Comment: @Topaco Sorry, it seems I read it wrong. 3DES can have 168-bits or 112-bits encryption keys. But it's still not 128-bits or 192-bits.

Comment: This is due to the parity bits, which is also explained in the Wikipedia article, or e.g. here: [Purpose of DES parity bits](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/34199). The post refers to DES but also applies to Triple DES. Note that 112 = 56*2 and 168 = 56*3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single DES has **56-bit effective key size, it is not 64**. 8-bit is used for [parity bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard#Key_schedule). 64-bit key size is in the standard and they are mostly discarded even before testing the parity of the each byte of the key.

DES was insecure for [bruteforce](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62772/18298) therefore 2DES and 3DES was suggested for a workaround.

3DES defined as `c = E(k3,D(k2,E(k1,m)))` where E means encrypt D means decrypt.

There are 3 options for 3DES

1. T3DEA which uses 3 independent keys, k1,k2, and, k3 with a 56*3 = 168-bit key size.
2. 2TDEA which uses 2 independent keys where k1 = k3 with a 56*2 = 112-bit key size
3. This time all keys are the same, k1=k2=k3 and we get a single DES, which already is insecure.

Although the option 1 and 2 can be seen as secure, they are not. The 64-bit block size of DES make it vulnerable to [sweet32 attack](https://sweet32.info/) like any other 64-it block size cipher. Either use AES with GCM or use ChaCha20 with Poly1305.

---

Note that the [pycryptodome document](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/des3.html) already mentions this in a similar manner, too, since this is the standard.

> key (bytes/bytearray/memoryview) – The secret key to use in the symmetric cipher. It must be 16 or 24 byte long. The parity bits will be ignored.

option 3 ( singe DES) is not supported and the library requires the keys 16 or 24 bytes where the parity bits are included. They are ignored, not checked. You can simply have 16 or 24-byte long random keys.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But there is another thing I'm wondering, they are saying that AES is much faster then 3DES in most of articles. But speed is literally same in Python, why?

Comment: Did you use DES or TDES on your measurements with option 1 or 2? Did you set the [use-aesni](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/aes.html)  option to true for AES? How did you measure and how many samples did you take, how long were the messages. Look at OpenSSL speed command to see the optimal one ( well, not true since side-channel protection is required). Note that you need special command to use [sotfware AES](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66199912/1820553)...

Comment: both AES and TDES encrypts a 300 characters long data instantly, and encrypted data is always same length. Also there are no such option to use option 1 or option 2. I can only use a 128-bits or 192-bits encryption keys and nothing changes except key size.

Comment: Option 1 and option 2 mean three and two keys, respectively. If you think that you have an unusual result, this can be a good question if you supply the code, data, timing and what is expected from the source and what you got. Currently, this is blindly guessing your tests...

Comment: I measured the encryption times of 3DES and AES with both using the same 128-bits key. The data I encrypted was 1640KB long. AES encrypted it in `1,18` seconds and 3DES encrypted in `1,19` seconds. Is that normal? (I tested it multiple times and AES was a little bit faster everytime)